# How do I get the duplicate record depending on SSN

Tags: mysql

I want to write an SQL query that gives me the user_id, last_name and Social_security_number for ALL users that have another user with the same last name and same RIGHT last four of the SSN. So if one has a full SSN and the other only last four, I only want to match on last four.  How do I write the Query to get all users with more than 1 records?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT orig.user_id, orig.last_name, orig.Social_security_number,
    dupe.user_id, dupe.last_name, dupe.Social_Security_number
FROM yourtable AS orig
INNER JOIN yourtable AS dupe ON
    (orig.last_name=dupe.last_name) AND
    (RIGHT(orig.Social_Security_number, 4) = RIGHT(dupe.Social_Security_Number, 4)) AND
    (orig.user_id <> dupe.user_id)
```

Basically do a self-join on whatever table you're storing this in, joining on the last name field, the last 4 digits of the SSN, and one edge case: since you're self joining, every record will match itself in the "dupe" table, so explicitly exclude that fake match.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why. the records returned some users id that just match one of the requirement. either last_name or last four digit of SSN

Answer (score 0):

This query will to that, assuming SSN is stored as a string:

```
SELECT
    u1.user_id, u1.last_name, u1.social_security_number
FROM
    users u1
WHERE
    EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            users u2
        WHERE
            u1.user_id <> u2.user_id
            AND u1.last_name = u2.last_name
            AND SUBSTRING(u1.social_security_number, -4) = SUBSTRING(u2.social_security_number, -4)
    )
```